# Displaying the filename of a HREF in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, filenames

I have a page with a download button like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.nl/filename.pdf" download>DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Below, I want (text) to automatically display "filename.pdf" (rather than having to do this by hand hundreds of times).

I found the script below that displays the filename of the PAGE but I want it to display the FILENAME of a HREF I've used on the actual page.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var segment_str = window.location.pathname;
var segment_array = segment_str.split( '/' );
var last_segment = segment_array.pop();
document.write(last_segment);

</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the directory where the files are located always the same? And is it always the root?

Comment: For now, yes it is! Later I might try to seperate it by maybe making a /downloads/ folder or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where you want the "text" to display... so I put it in a div

```
<a href="http://www.example.nl/filename.pdf" download>DOWNLOAD</a>


<div id="result">
</div>
```

The big change, is to get all the "a" tags, using getElementsByTagName... and then iterating over the list, and then you can use the string split, and pop off the last segment before appending it to a destination.

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i = 0;i < input.length; i++)
{
    var segment_str = input[i].href;
    var segment_array = segment_str.split( '/' );
    var last_segment = segment_array.pop();
    document.getElementById("result").innerText += last_segment; 
}
```

Comment: I have two "a hrefs" on the page. One to the file, one in the footer to a site but for some reason your script works perfectly. It does show the file of the download link which is great. So yep, seem to have answered my question! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

```
<div id=download1></div>

<script>
var filename = 'example.pdf';
$('#download1').html('<a href="http://www.example.nl/' + filename + '">' + filename + '</a>');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good one! However this uses the filename for the link itself, while I would like to seperate it from the Download link itself somewhere else on the page, as Jeremy's solution described.